# Scrapy isnt scraping the next page

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape article news from skynewsarabia.com

```
class SkyNewsSportsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'sky_news_sports'

sport = "https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/"
custom_settings = {
    'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["article_content", "tags"],
}
allowed_domains = ['www.skynewsarabia.com']

first_token = "1569266773000"
scrape_this_link = "https://api.skynewsarabia.com//rest/v2/latest.json?defaultSectionId=6&nextPageToken={}&pageSize=20&types=ARTICLE"
start_urls = [scrape_this_link.format(first_token)]
urls = []

def parse(self, response):
    articles = json.loads(response.text)

    # to get the link for each article we need to combine both the id and the urlFriendlySuffix in one link
    for article in range(0, len(articles["contentItems"])):
        article_id = articles["contentItems"][article]["id"]
        article_url = articles["contentItems"][article]["urlFriendlySuffix"]
        relative_link = article_id + "-" + article_url
        full_link = self.sport + relative_link
        self.urls.append(full_link)

    for url in self.urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    self.urls = []

    print("Before Check")
    self.first_token = articles["nextPageToken"]
    if self.first_token is not None:
        next_page = self.scrape_this_link.format(self.first_token)
        print("I am inside!")
        print(next_page)
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_details(self, response):
    pass
```

The basic idea here is that you first scrape a link which has 20 links. besides that, the first link has also a token for the next link which you need to add to the next URL so you can scrape the next 20 links.  However, the problem I am facing is that when you first run the script, it is taking the next token and get all the links of that token and then it stops! so I am just scraping 20 links only! when I print the first_token it's giving me something different than 1569266773000 which is provided by default in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `allowed_domains = ['www.skynewsarabia.com']` to `allowed_domains = ['skynewsarabia.com']`. Alternatively remove the `allowed_domains` variable completely.

Since you have specified the hostname `www` Scrapy filters the requests to `api.skynewsarabia.com` as offsite and the calls are just being dropped.

Additional tip: Try to use `self.logger.info` and `self.logger.debug` instead of the `print` commands in your code.

Comment: Yup, that's it, it's working, just had to delete the ```allowed_domains```. thanks for your explanations!